# turn javascript alert into a button or div for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, button, twitter-bootstrap

Basically there is a voting div when pressed the vote count goes up. if the same one is pressed again there is an alert that says 'you already voted!'. how can i turn this into a div or button that i can use with bootstrap so i can css it to make it look pretty.

```
var ivotings = Array();         // store the items with voting
var ar_elm = Array();       // store the items that will be send to votAjax()
var i_elm = 0;                  // Index for elements aded in ar_elm
var itemvotin = '';       // store the voting of voted item
var votingfiles = 'votingfiles/';      // directory with files for script
var advote = 0;      // variable checked in addVote(), if is 0 cann vote, else, not

// gets all DIVs, store in $ivotings, and in $ar_elm DIVs with class: "vot_plus", "vot_updown", and ID="vt_..", sends to votAjax()

var getVotsElm = function () {
  var obj_div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var nrobj_div = obj_div.length;
  for(var i=0; i<nrobj_div; i++) {
    // if contains class and id
    if(obj_div[i].className && obj_div[i].id) {
        var elm_id = obj_div[i].id;

      // if class "vot_plus", and id begins with "vt_"
      if((obj_div[i].className=='vot_plus' ) && elm_id.indexOf("vt_")==0) {
        ivotings[elm_id] = obj_div[i];       // store object item in $ivotings

        ar_elm[i_elm] = elm_id;     // add item_ID in $ar_elm array, to be send in json string tp php
        i_elm++;             // index order in $ar_elm
      }
    }
  }
  // if there are elements in "ar_elm", send them to votAjax()
  if(ar_elm.length>0) votAjax(ar_elm, '');      // if items in $ar_elm pass them to votAjax()
};

// add the ratting data to element in page
function addVotData(elm_id, vote, nvotes, renot) {
  // exists elm_id stored in ivotings
  if(ivotings[elm_id]) {
    // sets to add "onclick" for vote up (plus), if renot is 0
    var clik_up = (renot == 0) ? ' onclick="addVote(this, 1)"' : ' onclick="alert(\'you already voted!!!!!!\')"';

    // if vot_plus, add code with <img> 'votplus', else, if vot_updown1/2, add code with <img> 'votup',  'votdown'
    if(ivotings[elm_id].className == 'vot_plus') {    // simple vote
      ivotings[elm_id].innerHTML = '<h6>'+ vote+ '</h6><span><img src="'+votingfiles+'arrow.png" alt="1" title="" '+ clik_up+ '/></span>';
    };
}
}

// Sends data to votAjax(), that will be send to PHP to register the vote
function addVote(ivot, vote) {
  // if $advote is 0, can vote, else, alert message
  if(advote == 0) {
    var elm = Array();
    elm[0] = ivot.parentNode.parentNode.id;      // gets the item-name that will be voted

    ivot.parentNode.innerHTML = '';
    votAjax(elm, vote);
  }
  else alert('You already voted');
}

/*** Ajax ***/

// create the XMLHttpRequest object, according to browser
function get_XmlHttp() {
  var xmlHttp = null;           // will stere and return the XMLHttpRequest

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     // Forefox, Opera, Safari, ...
  else if(window.ActiveXObject) xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");     // IE

  return xmlHttp;
}

// sends data to PHP and receives the response
function votAjax(elm, vote) {
  var cerere_http =  get_XmlHttp();     // get XMLHttpRequest object

  // define data to be send via POST to PHP (Array with name=value pairs)
  var datasend = Array();
  for(var i=0; i<elm.length; i++) datasend[i] = 'elm[]='+elm[i];
  // joins the array items into a string, separated by '&'
  datasend = datasend.join('&')+'&vote='+vote;

  cerere_http.open("POST", votingfiles+'voting.php', true);         // crate the request

  cerere_http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    // header for POST
  cerere_http.send(datasend);       //  make the ajax request, poassing the data

  // checks and receives the response
  cerere_http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (cerere_http.readyState == 4) {
      // receives a JSON with one or more item:[vote, nvotes, renot]
      eval("var jsonitems = "+ cerere_http.responseText);

      // if jsonitems is defined variable
      if (jsonitems) {
        // parse the jsonitems object
        for(var votitem in jsonitems) {
          var renot = jsonitems[votitem][2];        // determine if the user can vote or not

          // if renot=3 displays alert that already voted, else, continue with the voting reactualization
           if(renot == 3) {
            alert("You already voted \n You can vote again tomorrow");
            window.location.reload(true);       // Reload the page
          }
          else addVotData(votitem, jsonitems[votitem][0], jsonitems[votitem][1], renot);    // calls function that shows voting
        }
      }

      // if renot is undefined or 2 (set to 1 NRVOT in voting.php), after vote, set $advote to 1
      if(vote != '' && (renot == undefined || renot == 2)) advote = 1;
      }
  }
}

// this function is used to access the function we need after loading page
function addLoadVote(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload; 

  // if the parameter is a function, calls it with "onload"
  // otherwise, adds the parameter into a function, and then call it
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') window.onload = func;
  else { 
    window.onload = function() { 
      if (oldonload) { oldonload(); } 
      func();
    } 
  } 
}

addLoadVote(getVotsElm);            // calls getVotsElm() after page loads
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First stop using **eval** this will complicate your code to no end. Instead assign events directly:

```
(function() {

  function init() {
    var el = document.getElementById("vote-button"); // Or use getElementsByClassName
    el.onclick = myClickerFunction;
  }

  window.onload = init;

})();
```

Then in your `myClickerFunction` do your check and choose to what to do. Either add the vote or remove a special div's class. This class is what you use to determine if it is visible or not:

```
<button id="vote-button">Vote</button>
<div id="warning" class="hidden">You can not vote more than once.</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#warning {
  /* Do your stuff */
}
.hidden { display: none; }
```

And finally your `myClickerFunction`:

```
function myClickerFunction() {
  var div = document.getElementById("warning");
  if (ivotings["warning"]) {
    addVote();
  }
  else {
    div.className = "";
  }
}
```

There is more to that and using a libaray like jQuery can afford you better code (`$("#warning").show()`) but the idea is simple enough.

Comment: garaths way seemed so much easier sigh.. im new to java well all code.. where do i add the first java function?

Comment: You wanted an answer in JavaScript not Java! If all you want is to use someone else's code that by all means use a library like @Garath suggested. I was only illustrating how you could do it by hand.

Comment: sorry javascript... i appreciate your answer i just dont know where to put the first function.. and garath's answer doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Also [O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/javascript/) has some great books on JavaScript! I also liked http://www.codecademy.com/ for beginners and some great folks on #javascript channel on [freenode](http://freenode.net/index.shtml)

Comment: ok thanks and ive done the codeacademy.com course on javascript but doesnt really seem to help in the real world.

Comment: thanks for your help @sukima. i can understand the code in the example. i actually made a tester one myself and got it to work but its just the actual voting script is very complex for me (look above). i have cleaned up the code a bit to make it more simple by taking out some of the code that's not being used and put yours in but no luck... for the img title i am using bootstrap tooltip to show 'vote!' and was told i could use this for the alert but no luck on this as well.. i will just accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://bootboxjs.com/ they have some cool examples: http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

Comment: i have seen all the examples from many sites.. i just dont know what to do with this code.. how or where do i add the strings in.. ive been on this for days now :(

Comment: Do following steps: Add this JS to your site: http://bootboxjs.com/bootbox.js. Then in you code use: 'bootbox.alert(\'you already voted!\')'
 instead of 'onclick="alert(\'you already voted!\')"'

Comment: <script src="http://bootboxjs.com/bootbox.js"></script> is was i added 'bootbox.alert(\'you already voted!\')'; what i changed.. doesn't work sir..